# "name".sock file is not being created

Tags: django, linux, ubuntu, deployment, gunicorn

I am trying to configure Gunicorn and Ngnix my Ngnix is configured correctly but Gunicorn is not. I am not able to create "name".sock file.

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After= network.target

[Service]
User=dexter
dexter=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/dexter/Documents/cpg_ad_tech/cpg_ad_tech ExecStart=/home/dexter/Documents/cpg_ad_tech/cpg_ad_tech_env/bin/gunicorn 
  --access-logfile - \
  --workers 3 \
  --bind unix:/home/dexter/Documents/cpg_ad_tech/cpg_ad_tech/cpg_ad_tech.sock \
  cpg_ad_tech.wsgi:application


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: try to get error details by journalctl -u gunicorn  --no-pager command. You may find something useful. after that try to give access to folder by this command sudo chown -R <<yourusername>>:www-data <<foldername>>.

Answer (score 0):

This could be problem with access rights. You can tray for tests with sudo

Answer (score 0):

Here is configure which really works.

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=user
Group=nginx
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/skystock
ExecStart=/var/www/env/env36/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/var/www/skystock/tmp/sky.sock skystock.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Of course, you should have the rights to access the folder.

```
sudo chown user:user /var/www/skystock
```